# Split the "master" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

On Q&A there's a tag [master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master). This is used for both the leader in replication and the SQL Server instance metadata database. These two are significantly different. Should we have separate tags for each? What should the tags be?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master) is a [bad tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) so we should remove it.

For replication, the following new tags might be good replacements (with the appropriate usage guidance for each):

- [master-slave-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-slave-replication)
- [master-master-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-master-replication)
- [multi-master-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-master-replication)

For the SQL Server system database usage, perhaps [master-system-database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-system-database).

I'm much less convinced that last tag would be useful though. How many people are looking to answer questions about the *master* system database specifically? Not many, I would venture.

---

There hasn't been too much feedback on this, so assuming general consent, I have:

- Removed [master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master) from all questions where it was present
- Created [master-system-database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-system-database) (seven questions) and added a brief description
- Created [master-slave-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-slave-replication) on one question (needs wiki)
- Created [master-master-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-master-replication) on one question (needs wiki)
- Not created [multi-master-replication](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-master-replication) because we have the broader [multi-master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multi-master)

The new replication tags will either be used or they won't. I'll leave that up to you all and future question askers.

Comment: What's more, I would encourage a more specific tag instead of one that's easier to type, so [tag:master-system-database]

Comment: @jcolebrand Added that in.

Comment: Totally agree with this